# SQL - Combine multiple columns into one column with more rows

Tags: sql, rows

I have a table with 20 columns that all display the same thing. I'm not sure why my company set it up like this, but I cannot make changes to the table.

With that in mind, here is what I need to do. I need to populate a drop down list with insurance company names. Therefore I need to find unique values across the entire table.

Using a `Group By` clause is out of the question because I need unique values across the entire table. No single column contains all the possible values. My only thought was to combine all the columns of the table together. I've seen this done using two pipes ( || ). But that concatenates the columns which does not help me.

I need to join two (or twenty) columns together and add their rows together. I.e. if I started out with 20 columns and 100 rows, I need to have one column with 2000 rows. This way I can select unique values using the Group By clause.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Sample of what I'm trying to accomplish:

Sample original table:

```
    --Ins1-----Ins2---Ins3---Ins4-
    Medicaid-Medicare-------------
    ---------Medicaid-----No 485--
    Blue Cross--------------------
    -------Home Health----Medicare
```

Table I need to construct:

```
    --Column1--
    -Medicaid--
    -----------
    Blue Cross-
    -----------
    -Medicare--
    -Medicaid--
    -----------
    Home Health
    -----------
    -----------
    -----------
    -----------
    -----------
    --No 485---
    -----------
    -Medicare--
```

Maybe my logic is wrong. This is the only way I could see to find unique information across the entire table.

Comment: can you post some sample data and what you want to return as the final product?  Also what RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this is SQL Server, then it sounds like you need to use [UNPIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to perform this transformation.

Sample UNPIVOT (See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/44083/4) with Demo):

```
select ques, answer
FROM t1
unpivot
(
    answer
    for ques in (col1, col2, col3, col4)
) u
```

The UNPIVOT will transform your data from columns to rows.

Comment: I don't believe this is SQL Server. We use a VBScript to access the SQL from an XML interface. Will this technique still work?

Comment: I got it to work using the Union all clause.
For future reference, here is how it's done:       
        `Select ins1 as insurance
        from insurance
        where ins1 is not null
        union all
        select in2 as insurance
        where ins2 is not null`
etc.. or use this website http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2008/04/23/unpivot.aspx

Comment: @phileaton You said you wanted unique, but your example has duplicates.  If you want to remove duplicates, use UNION instead of UNION ALL